# WHERE clause on value 1 (if present), or value 2 (if not)

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL Server 2014

Considering a table like this:

```
idkey    companyid    |column 1    |column 2
------------------------------------------------
1        0             apple        fruit 1
2        0             orange       fruit 2
3        0             grapes       fruit 3
4        10            banana       fruit 2
```

CompanyId = 0 is the default list of values; other company ids can override individual values or take the default list.

Note that for companyid = 10, 'fruit 2' has a different value specified for column 1.

How do I select companyid 0's values with the company 10 override, as in:

```
idkey    companyid    |column 1    |column 2
------------------------------------------------
1        0             apple        fruit 1
4        10            banana       fruit 2
3        0             grapes       fruit 3
```

Is there a way to do this with a single SQL statement, or do I need to create a stored procedure and temp table? I've searched quite a bit, but apparently can't find a way to phrase the question simply enough for a search to return useful answers.

Comment: What if there be more than one override?  What if more than one record can be overriden at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select coalesce(t2.idkey, t1.idkey) as idkey,
       coalesce(t2.companyid, t1.companyid) as companyid,
       coalesce(t2.column1, t1.column1) as column1,
       coalesce(t2.column2, t1.column2) as column2
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.column2 = t2.column2
                       and t2.companyid <> 0
where t1.companyid = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Say company ID that you are interested in is 10. Your query could be:

```
declare @id bigint = 10

select 
  coalesce(t2.idkey, t1.idkey),
  coalesce(t2.companyid, t1.companyid) companyid,
  coalesce(t2.column1, t1.column1) column1,
  t1.column2

from table t1
  left join table t2 on t2.companyid = @id and t1.column2 = t2.column2
```

It makes sense to create a stored procedure or table-valued function with a single `@id` parameter

```
create procedure tableWithOverrides(@id bigint)
as
begin
select 
  coalesce(t2.idkey, t1.idkey),
  coalesce(t2.companyid, t1.companyid) companyid,
  coalesce(t2.column1, t1.column1) column1,
  t1.column2

from table t1
  left join table t2 on t2.companyid = @id and t1.column2 = t2.column2
end
```